# Check dataframe data with other dataframe data

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe like that

```
> print(A)
     5 3 7 6 11 4 20 8 16 18
 r01 1 1 1 1  1 1  1 1  1  0
 r02 0 0 0 0  0 0  0 1  1  0
 r03 1 0 1 0  1 1  0 0  0  0
 r04 0 1 0 0  0 1  0 1  0  1
 r05 1 1 0 1  1 1  0 0  1  1
```

And other like that

```
> print(B)
     head_req_ID tail_req_ID
1         r04         r01
2         r01         r02
3         r05         r03
```

For each column of A I have to check the B dataframe, it's a list of requeriments, for example:

- r01 will be 0 if r04 is 0, I have to have 1 in r04 for take r01 and
  this for all B rows.

On the other hand, if r01 it's 1 and r04 it's 0, I will set r01 value to 0.

**EDIT**

I will try to explain with a image example

[image]

Comment: I edited it, sorry for my mistakes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was not explained properly but I took a stab at what I think you might be looking for:

```
# your data
m <- matrix(c(1 ,1 ,1, 1  ,1 ,1  ,1 ,1  ,1  ,0,
  0 ,0 ,0 ,0  ,0 ,0  ,0 ,1  ,1  ,0,
  1 ,0 ,1 ,0  ,1 ,1  ,0 ,0  ,0  ,0,
  0 ,1 ,0 ,0  ,0 ,1  ,0 ,1  ,0  ,1,
  1 ,1, 0 ,1  ,1 ,1  ,0 ,0  ,1  ,1), byrow= T, ncol = 10)
dimnames(m) <- list(paste0("r0",1:5), c(5,3,7,6,11,4,20,8,16,18))
A <- as.data.frame(m)
B <- data.frame(head_req_ID = c("r04","r01","r05"), tail_req_ID = c("r01","r02","r03"))

# For each column of A, check B
# if r04 == 0, r01 <- 0 
# if r01 == 1 & r04 == 1, r01 <- 0
A.new <- A # save it again
B.new <- data.frame(head_req_ID = c(4,1,5), tail_req_ID = c(1,2,3)) # I would not use "r01" but rather 1

# use B.new[,1] to change B.new[,2]
for(i in 1:nrow(B.new)) A.new[B.new[i,2],] <- ifelse(A[B.new[i,1],] == 0 , 0, 1)
# which is the same thing as saying
for(i in 1:nrow(B.new)) A.new[B.new$tail_req_ID[i],] <- ifelse(A.new[B.new$head_req_ID[i],] == 0, 0, 1)

A
#    5 3 7 6 11 4 20 8 16 18
#r01 1 1 1 1  1 1  1 1  1  0
#r02 0 0 0 0  0 0  0 1  1  0
#r03 1 0 1 0  1 1  0 0  0  0
#r04 0 1 0 0  0 1  0 1  0  1
#r05 1 1 0 1  1 1  0 0  1  1

A.new
#    5 3 7 6 11 4 20 8 16 18
#r01 0 1 0 0  0 1  0 1  0  1
#r02 0 1 0 0  0 1  0 1  0  1
#r03 1 1 0 1  1 1  0 0  1  1
#r04 0 1 0 0  0 1  0 1  0  1
#r05 1 1 0 1  1 1  0 0  1  1
```

Comment: I used your solution, I changed some things and it's works !! So much thanks :)

Comment: Glad it worked! Great picture edit.